# Hyper-V 2012R2 in workgroup: can't access via Hyper-V Manager after joining client to domain

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012-r2, workgroup, windows-10

After joining my Windows 10 workstation to the domain, I am unable to manage via Hyper-V Manager. The Hyper-V 2012R2 server remains in a workgroup.

When I try to log into Hyper-V Manager as the vmserver's local administrator account, I get the error "You do not have the required permission to complete this task. Contact the administrator of the authorization policy for the computer 'vm-server'.

I have my trusted hosts set with an *[domain name], and hvremote checks out on the server with no errors. Firewalls are off between the server and workstation. Local Administrator account is listed as a stored credential in cmdkey, even.

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Can you explain why your client is joined to the domain but your server is on a workgroup?

Comment: I don't have a physical DC at the moment. Running a lab environment.

Answer (score 1):

Since hvremote checks out, perhaps the below may help?

Referencing this link http://www.josephturley.com/solved-required-permission/

> It seems a bit odd to me that I can’t access VM’s located on my local
>   machine, especially when I’m a local administrator.
>
> After looking around a bit, I found that there is a local Hyper-V
>   Administrators group that by default is empty. Add yourself to the
>   group by doing the following:
>
> Access the Computer Management interface.
>
> In Windows 7 and Windows 8, this can be found by simply searching for
>   Computer Management.
>
> Expand the Local Users and Groups section and click on Groups
>
> Double click on the Hyper-V Administrators group
>
> In the Dialogue box, click Add… and then enter your user name in the
>   box and hit OK.
>
> Hit OK again and close out of Computer Management
>
> One more caveat. In my experience, I needed to log out and log back
>   into Windows for the changes to work.